# Conekta, Alguien sabe de donde obtener account_created_at y first_paid_at para pagos OxxoPay

Tags: api

Intento crear una orden para pagos OxxoPay de conekta con los siguientes datos:

```
{
    "line_items": [
        {
            "name": "Boleto de prueba",
            "unit_price": 16127,
            "quantity": 1,
            "antifraud_info": {
                "trip_id": "01",
                "departs_at": 1654732989,
                "arrives_at": 1654819389,
                "ticket_class": "Ordinario",
                "seat_number": "01",
                "passenger_type": "Adulto",
                "origin": "Tijuana",
                "destination": "Los Mochis",
                "paid_transactions": 1
            }
        }
    ],
    "currency": "MXN",
    "customer_info": {
        "name": "Juan Manuel Ramirez",
        "email": "juanmanual999@gmail.com",
        "phone": "+525555555555"
    },
    "charges": [
        {
            "payment_method": {
                "type": "oxxo_cash",
                "expires_at": 1654653789
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Pero obtengo como resultado:

```
{
    "details": [
        {
            "debug_message": "The \"customer_info attribute antifraud_info attribute paid_transactions\" is missing.",
            "message": "El parametro paid_transactions\" es requerido.",
            "param": "customer_info.antifraud_info.paid_transactions",
            "code": "conekta.errors.parameter_validation.customer_info.antifraud_info.paid_transactions.missing"
        },
        {
            "debug_message": "The \"customer_info attribute antifraud_info attribute account_created_at\" is missing.",
            "message": "El parametro account_created_at\" es requerido.",
            "param": "customer_info.antifraud_info.account_created_at",
            "code": "conekta.errors.parameter_validation.customer_info.antifraud_info.account_created_at.missing"
        },
        {
            "debug_message": "The \"customer_info attribute antifraud_info attribute first_paid_at\" is missing.",
            "message": "El parametro first_paid_at\" es requerido.",
            "param": "customer_info.antifraud_info.first_paid_at",
            "code": "conekta.errors.parameter_validation.customer_info.antifraud_info.first_paid_at.missing"
        }
    ],
    "object": "error",
    "type": "parameter_validation_error",
    "log_id": "629fe73d0211a6514381eb0b"
}
```

Ni siquiera entiendo que hacen esos datos en una referencia Oxxo pero la única respuesta que he recibido de conekta hasta el momento es que se requieren, sin saber de donde obtenerlos.

Estoy utilizando el sdk de php de conekta para crear la orden.

Ya he intentado con soporte técnico de conekta pero sigo sin obtener respuesta sobre la naturaleza de los datos o de dónde los obtengo.

A su vez la documentación los marca como opcionales, pero "por el giro de la empresa" deben estar esos datos, aunque si el cliente se introduce en la orden es porque no existe.

Si alguien sabe algo de eso se lo agradezco de antemano. Gracias.